# ExtJS: Is there a way to shift tabpanel's Tab icon from left to right of the Tab's title?

Tags: css, extjs, extjs6

Does ExtJS provide a way to show icon for tab title in front of title instead of the default behavior?

Default Behviour:

```
---------------
| +  Tab 1    |
---------------
```

Required Behavior:

```
---------------
|  Tab 1  +   |
---------------
```

Code Example:

```
Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
  plain: true,
  items: [{
    title: "Tab 1",
    iconCls: "icon-class-plus",
  }, {
    title: "Tab 2",
  }],
  renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

icon-class-plus is a CSS class that contain &:after pseudo element for setting a glyph icon for plus sign.

Comment: Which is it? Ext4 or Ext6?

Comment: Ext6 will do...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `iconAlign` config:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
            items: [{
                title: "Tab 1",
                iconCls: "x-fa fa-car",
                iconAlign: 'right'
            }],
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/21pe)